# Memory allocation for string passed as array

Tags: c++

I have very basic question. In the below code we are passing string as argument to someFunc function where it takes char array as argument. How will memory get allocated for a[], and where will the memory get allocated ? Also how it will be decided how much memory to allocate in case of different sized strings ?

```
int someFunc(char a[])
{ 
   //do something
}

int main( )
{
   someFunc("Frankenstein is dead");

   someFunc("Hello there");
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do note that C and C++ are two very different languages, and semantics for things like literal strings are different between them.

Comment: From C++ perspective , how will the memory be allocated, I know we can make use of string class as well. But I have a limitation in my case.

Comment: LuisGp agreed. When copy constructor comes into picture memory allocation happens in heap. Am I right ?

Comment: Your function receives a `char[]` which is equivalent to `char*` in this case, so no memory allocation happens when calling the function. Instead, both calls passed a string literal, that is declared by the compilar as `const char *`. The allocation of both literals will occur when the compiler considers.

Comment: @Akshay, I deleted my previous comment because you didn't use `std::string` but `char[]` and things go in other way ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot Luis you gave me a right idea on what I was confused about :)

Answer (score 10):

When declaring an argument as an array in C++, it's actually declared as a *pointer*.

That is, your function is really

```
someFunc(char* a) { ... }
```

That means, what is passed is a pointer to the first element of the literal strings.

Also note that in C++ a literal string is an array of *constant* characters. So it decays to the type `const char*`. Which means your argument have to be of that type as well.

How the constant string literal arrays are allocated are really irrelevant and an implementation detail, but it's typically the compiler saves the strings together with the generated code in the executable program file. This lets them be loaded into memory by the operating system program loader together with the code, and no "dynamic" allocation for the strings themselves are made.